# routes.MapRoute issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am receiving the following error

> Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'User'. This
>   can happen if the route that services this request
>   ('Mobile/{controller}/{action}/{id}') does not specify namespaces to
>   search for a controller that matches the request. If this is the case,
>   register this route by calling an overload of the 'MapRoute' method
>   that takes a 'namespaces' parameter.

I have created the following in my Global.asax.cs

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
routes.MapRoute(
"Mobile",
"Mobile/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
 new { controller = "User", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
 new string[] { "YourApp.Controllers.Mobile" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
"Other",
"Other/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
new { controller = "User", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
new string[] { "YourApp.Controllers.Other" }
);
```

From what I've read, adding these should take care of my issue.

Comment: Can you try naming your parameters, since there is also a parameter "constraints" accepting an object, your namespace string might be coming into this parameter instead of the namespace parameter..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the `UserController` class is within the namespace `YourApp.Controllers.Mobile`?
That error should also mention all the matching controllers that have been found with their full namespaces. Which ones are those and which namespaces do they have?

When you specify a namespace, if the controller is not found in that namespace MVC will then resort to its default behaviour. The default behaviour being that any public controller class named `UserController` is a match.

For helping diagnostic the error, you could disable this fallback behaviour by adding the route in this way:

```
Route myRoute = routes.MapRoute(
    "Mobile",
    "Mobile/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
     new { controller = "User", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
     new [] { "YourApp.Controllers.Mobile" }
);
myRoute.DataTokens["UseNamespaceFallback"] = false;
```

After disabling the fallback, MVC will only look at the namespaces specified. If the controller is not in that namespace then you will get a 404 error. In that case you will be certain that you are not setting the correct namespace.

Hope this helps!